# postgresql group_by with date in localtime

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, utc

I know there are `date` function in postgresql

`select date(date_time_field) from .. group by (date(date_time_field)`

However the resulting date is utc date it seems.
I want to group_by by local date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select date(date_time_field at time zone 'brt')
from ..
group by 1
```

[at time zone](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)